# Unable to click on a sub value of a tab, getting 'element not visible' exception in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Trying to click on the 'E-Commerce Demo Site' in the 'DEMO SITES' tab in 'http://toolsqa.com/' website using the below mentioned ways. But unable to click on it. Kindly help me on this issue.

Code1:

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.linkText("E-Commerce Demo Site"))));
  driver.findElement(By.linkText("E-Commerce Demo Site")).click();
```

Code2:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#main-nav > li.menu-item.menu-item-type-custom.menu-item-object-custom.menu-item-has-children.menu-item-17611.dt-mega-menu.mega-auto-width.mega-column-1.has-children > ul > li.menu-item.menu-item-type-custom.menu-item-object-custom.menu-item-21575.dt-mega-parent.wf-1.first.level-arrows-on")).click();
```

Code3:

```
WebElement subNav = driver.findElement(By.className("sub-nav"));
List < WebElement > subNavValues = subNav.findElements(By.tagName("li"));

subNavValues.get(0).click();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
     Actions ac;
 ac = new Actions(dr);
ac.MoveToElement(dr.FindElement(By.LinkText("DEMOSITES"))).Perform();
```

Then use any of the following xpaths to click on the submenu:

1."//span[contains(text(),'E-Commerce Demo Site')]"

2."//a[@href='http://store.demoqa.com']"

```
dr.findelement(By.xpath(xpath)).click();
```

Comment: I'm getting below error while using the above code: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"DEMOSITES"}

Comment: there was some copy paste mistake. Use the following code. It should work:                                                                                                     ac = new Actions(dr);
  ac.MoveToElement(dr.FindElement(By.LinkText("DEMO SITES"))).Perform();

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to move to the "Demo sites" span. You have to use the Actions class to move to this element using the function `moveToElement()`. For the element search for the span with the text "DEMO SITES".
2. Wait for the sub-menu to be displayed. Use webdriver wait on the element ul with class='sub-nav'. `new WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(sub-menu webelement)).`
3. Then you click on the 'E-Commerce Demo Site' link. Which is in the span with the text.

You can figure out the exact syntax.

Answer (score 1):

After Maximizing of your window try below things

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//nav[@id='navigation']/ul/li[9]/a/span"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(elem).build().perform();
```

This is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this it works fine for me:

```
@Test
public void qaToolsNavigation() {
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    By demoSitesMenuItem = By.xpath("//span[text()='DEMO SITES']");
    By eCommerceSubMenuItem = By.xpath("(//span[text()='E-Commerce Demo Site']/..)[1]");
    driver.get("http://toolsqa.com/");
    waitForVisibility(demoSitesMenuItem, 10);
    action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(demoSitesMenuItem)).build().perform();
    waitForVisibility(eCommerceSubMenuItem, 10);
    driver.findElement(eCommerceSubMenuItem).click();
}

private void waitForVisibility(By locator, int timeToWait) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeToWait);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Try This:
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*//span[contains(text(),'E-Commerce Demo 
Site')]")).click();